# LINQ Distinct not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, linq, distinct, linq-to-objects

I have the following simple class

```
public class Person : IEquatable<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person other) 
    {
        return Name.Equals(other.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am creating an array of persons, calling distinct on them and pass the default Equality Comparer, which is the one implemented by `IEquatable<Person>`

```
var persons = new[] {new Person("foo"), new Person("Foo"), new Person("bar"), new Person("Bar")};
persons.Distinct(EqualityComparer<Person>.Default);
```

When I inspect the distincted persons, I am expecting an `IEnumerable<Person>` containing `foo, bar`. However the contents are `foo, Foo, bar, Bar`

When I initialize the List with `foo, foo, bar, bar` the result is as expected. So it seems to me as if `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` in the `Person.Equals` method is ignored.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Some other remarks (your problem already been solved by answers). You should consider checking `other` for `null` in `Equals`. Since `Person` might be derived from (it is not a `sealed` class) also consider saying `if (GetType() != other.GetType()) { return false; }`. Note that your object is mutable (`Name` can be changed after object is constructed), and that mutable objects should not be mutated while contained in dictionaries or hash sets. Do override the virtual `Object.Equals(object obj)` by saynig `return obj as Person;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `GetHashCode()` get a case-**in**sensitive Hash Code at the moment, it will be a different hash code for upper and lower case `Name`'s.

For example:

```
public override int GetHashCode() 
{ 
    return Name.ToUpperInvariant().GetHashCode(); 
}
```

Comment: `ToUpperInvariant()` would be more efficient than `ToLower()`.

Comment: @m-y Thanks, I was just going from Memory, I knew there would be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Your GetHashCode() will return different hash codes for objects who should be considered identical.